# Function("last name, first name") reports: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, input

I need to create a function that takes input a string containing a name in the "Last_Name, First_Name" format and prints a welcome message w/ first name first and the last name last and tells the person the length of their first name. The function should be able to handle a wrong input and print a message: Input format error: please use "Last_Name, First_Name". The below is what I have so far and the error I'm getting. I haven't been able to figure out how to create an error message if the user enters info in the wrong format:

```
input_name = input("Enter your name in last name, first name format")
Last_name, First_name =input_name.strip().split(',')
Full_name=First_name + ' ' + Last_name
print(Full_name + ' your first name is ' + len(First_name) + ' letters in length')
```

---

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-14516c1daf2c> in <module>()
  2 Last_name, First_name =input_name.strip().split(',')
  3 Full_name=First_name + ' ' + Last_name
----> 4 print(Full_name + ' your first name is ' + len(First_name) + ' letters in length')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because of concatenating len(First_name) which returns an integer with string.

You can use regex pattern match for validating the name.

```
import re

def is_valid(name: str):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*$')
    return pattern.match(name)


def print_welcome_message(name: str):
    if is_valid(name):
        last_name, first_name = map(str.strip, name.split(','))
        message = f'{first_name} {last_name} your first name is {len(first_name)} letters in length'
        print(message)
    else:
        print("Input format error: please use 'Last_Name, First_Name'")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_name = input("Enter your name in last name, first name format")
    print_welcome_message(input_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`len()` returns an integer - to concatenate it with a string, you need to turn that into a string first. You can do that with the `str()` function.

```
print(Full_name + ' your first name is ' + str(len(First_name)) + ' letters in length')
```

To answer the second part of this question: how to tell the user that the input format is wrong, you can do some simple error handling. If the input format is wrong, the line

```
Last_name, First_name =input_name.strip().split(',')
```

could throw some sort of exception (Too many values to unpack, not enough values to unpack etc.). So you can do this:

```
try:
    Last_name, First_name =input_name.strip().split(',')
except:
    print("Input format is wrong")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Of course there are more robust ways of doing this. For example, you can:

1) Use a regex to check the input format

2) Check the input string for existence of `,` before splitting

3) Check the length of the string array after `.split()` and give the user a more specific error message